# Mongodb C# driver Perform string contains query on a property in an embedded document

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the below simplified model:

```
public class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public IList<ComponentProperty> Components { get; private set; }

}

public class ComponentProperty
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

}
```

I want to be able to find any entity whose property value string contains the search string, and to that end I wrote the following query, based on recommendation [here](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2013/12/11/insenstive-search-with-mongo-with-c-and-linq-provider/), which implicitly uses Regex:

```
var query = _context.GetCollection<Entity>()
                        .AsQueryable()
                        .Where(t => t.Components.Any(c => c.Value.ToLower() == queryOptions.Filter));
```

This query produces the following json, and (incorrectly) returns 0 rows:

```
aggregate([{ "$match" : { "Components" : { "$elemMatch" : { "Value" : /^'green'$/i} } } }])
```

However, the hand-crafted query that produces the correct results is the below:

```
aggregate([{ "$match" : { "Components" : { "$elemMatch" : { "Value" :  {$regex: '.*green.*' } } } } }])
```

Perhaps, there is something I have overlooked in my approach using the c# driver, and any pointers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your `where` clause to this:

```cs
.Where(e => e.Components.Any(c => c.Value.ToLower().Contains(queryOptions.Filter)))
```

which produces this aggregation:

```java
db.Entity.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "Components.Value": /green/is
        }
    }
])
```

here's a test program:

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverFlow
{
    public class Ntity : Entity
    {
        public IList<ComponentProperty> Components { get; set; }
    }

    public class ComponentProperty
    {
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }

    }

    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            new DB("test");

            new Ntity
            {
                Components = new List<ComponentProperty> {
                    new ComponentProperty {
                        PropertyName = "test",
                        Value = "the RED color" }
                }
            }.Save();

            new Ntity
            {
                Components = new List<ComponentProperty> {
                    new ComponentProperty {
                        PropertyName = "test",
                        Value = "the Green color" }
                }
            }.Save();

            var result = DB.Queryable<Ntity>()
                           .Where(e => e.Components.Any(c => c.Value.ToLower().Contains("green")))
                           .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I finally noted that the filter 'green', actually had the single quote passed in from the browser, silly me to have doubted the contains worked any other way. Thanks for your help, I got the ref query to validate mine against